# How would you receive a file sent with 'sendfile'?

Tags: c, string, recv, sendfile

I'm trying to implement a basic file server. I have been trying to use the sendfile command found here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile I'm using TCP.

I can have it send fine, but its sending in binary and I'm not sure if thats the hang up.

I am trying to receive the file with recv, but it isn't coming through correctly. 
Is there a special way to receive a binary file, and put it into a string?

EDIT: 
Asked to supply some code, here it is:

SENDFILE Call (from Server process)

```
FILE * file = fopen(filename,"rb");
    if ( file != NULL)   
    {            
        /*FILE EXISITS*/ 
        //Get file size (which is why we opened in binary)
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
        int sz = ftell(file);
        fseek(file,0L,SEEK_SET);

        //Send the file
        sendfile(fd,(int)file,0,sz);
        //Cleanup 
        fclose(file);
    }
```

RECIEVE Call (from Client process, even more basic than a loop, just want a single letter)

```
//recieve file
    char fileBuffer[1000];
    recv(sockfd,fileBuffer,1,0);
    fprintf(stderr,"\nContents:\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"%c",fileBuffer[0]);
```

EDIT: wrote some code for checking return values. sendfile is giving errno 9 - bad file number. Which im assuming is at my second file descriptor in the call (the one for the file i'm sending). I cast it as an int because sendfile was complaining it wasn't an int.

How should I use send file given the file pointer code I have used above in th sendfile call?

Comment: Can you supply some code, your sendfile call and your recv-loop?

Comment: Always, always, always check the return value of your system calls (fseek, sendfile, recv).  And include the result(s) in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `sendfile()` with a `FILE*`, you need a file descriptor as given by `open()`, `close()` and friends. You cannot just cast a FILE* into an int and thinking it would work.

Maybe you should read the `sendfile()` manpage for more information.

Comment: thanks, i just had to use open instead of fopen. Did not realize the difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special way. You just receive with `read()` or `recv()`.

Probably, you've got your receiving code wrong.

Comment: so if I were to recv into a string, everything should turn out fine?

Comment: depends on how you do it. Don't expect any socket reading code to read whole file at once, though. Especially if it is big.

Comment: Yea, i have it in a loop. But even if i could get the first few letters to know it was reading right. I'll have a look at it soon.